# Counting Posts with multiple taxonomy and terms condition using MySQL and AJAX

Tags: ajax, wpdb, sql

I am trying to get the number of posts with multiple taxonomy and terms using MySQL and AJAX. but I cannot get the desired result with my query. I derived my query in this wpdb query and sadly it returns 0. I am hoping anyone can give me the exact sql query for this one. very much appreciated.

Here is my current Query:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_content
FROM wp_posts AS p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON ('p.ID' = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE   p.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND p.post_type = 'company'
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'repair_duration' 
    AND t.name = 'days'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

this one is for a single condition, and I am trying to achieve searching with multiple values of terms. I tried using WHERE IN but still no luck.

Example:
Search A company that has taxonomy of repair_duration and terms of day, minutes and has taxonomy of repair_quality and terms of good, best

I really appreciate your responses.
currently I am working on wpdb query on ajax, if that's possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an SQL query instead of WP_Query?

Comment: Yes, there's a reason. I am planning to display the number of posts during filtering. these terms are looped into checkboxes and radio buttons so if a user clicked a checkbox, the query is changing in realtime.

Comment: But nothing in this query can't be done with WP_Query.

Comment: Yup, I am aware of it. I already achieved this one on wp_query with multiple taxonomies and terms. the problem is, I wanna show the number of posts with the selected filters without reloading the page, that's why I used the ajax approach.

Comment: What does that have to do with using SQL instead of WP_Query?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you can use wp_query on separate file for ajax.

Comment: If you could use `wpdb` on that file, then you could also use `WP_Query` - try `new WP_Query()` in your AJAX code and see if it works? And how are you doing the AJAX? Is it via `admin-ajax.php`? Or does your script send the AJAX request to the same page?

Comment: I am currently exploring that part. Including wp-config, admin-ajax, wp-load and other needed core files. I only say that I've referenced the sql based on the wpdb query.

Comment: Well then, you don't seem to be doing the AJAX (the PHP side) properly.. there's no need to manually load WordPress, if you do your AJAX the right way (or the "WordPress way"). See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) for the `admin-ajax.php` route.

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks Sally CJ

Comment: My pleasure. And you should also check the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and then consider using the REST API instead to handle your AJAX request - excerpt from the REST API handbook: "*If you want a structured, extensible, and simple way to get data in and out of WordPress, you probably want to use the REST API.*".

Comment: I think the rest API will be capable of addressing my problem. just one question, to which file are they registering the custom post types? functions.php?

Comment: Yes, the [functions file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/) can be used, but it's [recommended](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) that you put custom post types in a plugin rather than a theme. And BTW, please tag the person you're replying to so that he/she gets notified of your replies, @Blitzkriegfest ..